# Answer multiple console prompts using .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, console-application

I have a console application that requires multiple inputs. How would I go about making a batch file that starts and provides input to the prompts as they come up. I know how to start the program and answer the first prompt, but not the ones after. The commands I use are:

> `echo username | consoleApp.exe`

but it only provides input for the first one.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried providing them in order?

```batch-file
@(  Echo username
    Echo password
    Echo something
    …etc.
) | consoleApp.exe
```